# Ignore blank value in Pivot table Row labels with Apache POI

Tags: java, java-8, apache-poi, pivot-table

I am trying to remove the blank row tables from the Pivot table. I couldn't find the documentation with Apache POI around it.

[image]

Is there anybody achieved this or knows whether Apache POI supports this or not?